# Change font of certain symbols and or characters

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts

So basically like the question states I need to be able and change the font of certain characters and symbols in my HTML without affecting how it looks. Currently, the HTML uses the Gotham font and that font does not support certain symbols. Arial works with all symbols. To change the font of these characters I used the following code:

```
        var str = $('.text').text(),
            letters = '';
        for (var i = 0, len = str.length; i < len; i++) {
            if (str[i].match(/[¢€£¥©®™‰µ·•…′″§¶ß‹›«»‘’“”<>≤≥–—¯‾¤¦¨¡¿ˆ˜°−±÷⁄×¹²³¼½¾ƒ∫∑∞√∼≅≈≠≡∈∉∋∏∧∨¬∩∪∂∀∃∅∇∗∝∠´¸ªº†‡ÀÁÂÃÅÆÇÈÉÊËĒÌÍÎÏĪÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØŒŠÙÚÛÜŪÝŸȲÞàáâãäåāæçèéêëēìíïīðñòóôõöøōœšùúûüýþÿȳΑΒΓΔΕΖΘΛΞΟΠΡΣΦΨΩαβγδεζηθικλμνξοπρςστυφψωℵϖℜϒ℘ℑ←↑→↓↔↵⇐⇒⇓⇔∴⊂⊃⊄⊆⊇⊕⊗⊥⋅⌈⌉⌊⌋〈〉◊♠♣♥♦]/i)) {
                letters += '<span style="font:20px Arial;">' + str[i] + '</span>';
            }else {
                letters +=str[i];
            }
        }
        $('.text').html(letters);
```

While this code does its job, change the font of symbols to trial, it has two major problems. The first is that the Gotham font goes away when the text is rebuilt and the second is that all formatting (like

tags) disappear during the rebuild.

For example this:

```
<p>sadf sdajkf hksadjfh s</p>
<p>Symbols:</p>
<p>¢€£¥©®™‰µ·•…′″§¶ß‹›«»‘’“”&lt;&gt;≤≥–—¯‾¤¦¨¡¿ˆ˜°−±÷⁄×¹²³¼½¾ƒ∫∑∞√∼≅≈≠≡∈∉∋∏∧∨¬∩∪∂∀∃∅∇∗∝∠´¸ªº†‡ÀÁÂÃÅÆÇÈÉÊËĒÌÍÎÏĪÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØŒŠÙÚÛÜŪÝŸȲÞàáâãäåāæçèéêëēìíïīðñòóôõöøōœšùúûüýþÿȳΑΒΓΔΕΖΘΛΞΟΠΡΣΦΨΩαβγδεζηθικλμνξοπρςστυφψωℵϖℜϒ℘ℑ←↑→↓↔↵⇐⇒⇓⇔∴⊂⊃⊄⊆⊇⊕⊗⊥⋅⌈⌉⌊⌋⟨⟩◊♠♣♥♦</p>
```

Turns into this:

```
sadf sdajkf hksadjfh s Symbols:
<span style="font:20px Arial;">¢</span>
<span style="font:20px Arial;">€</span>
...
```

Basically, the p tags (and with it the spacing) disappears. Is there any simple way to fix this problem??

Comment: The simple answer is: use a font, that supports all the characters you need. It will save you a lot of time and script overhead...

Answer (score 1):

The solution was fairly simple actually. Just use .html() and make sure you aren't matching with any important HTML Syntax characters like '\' or '<>'.

```
        var str = $('.text').html(),
            letters = '';
        for (var i = 0, len = str.length; i < len; i++) {
            if (str[i].match(/[µ·•¶ß¯‾¤¦¨¡¿ˆ˜°−±÷⁄×¹²³¼½¾ƒ∫∑∞√∼≅≈≠≡∈∉∋∏∧∨¬∩∪∂∀∃∅∇∗∝∠ªº†‡ÀÁÂÃÅÆÇÈÉÊËĒÌÍÎÏĪÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØŒŠÙÚÛÜŪÝŸȲÞàáâãäåāæçèéêëēìíïīðñòóôõöøōœšùúûüýþÿȳΑΒΓΔΕΖΘΛΞΟΠΡΣΦΨΩαβγδεζηθικλμνξοπρςστυφψωℵϖℜϒ℘ℑ←↑→↓↔↵⇐⇒⇓⇔∴⊂⊃⊄⊆⊇⊕⊗⊥⋅⌈⌉⌊⌋◊♠♣♥♦]/i)) {
                letters += '<span style="font:20px Arial;">' + str[i] + '</span>';
            }else {
                letters +=str[i];
            }
        }
        $('.text').html(letters);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question. I would suggest focusing your JavaScript function on the section that will have the symbols in it to simplify the process.

Give your section with the chars in a class name for example 'myChars'

```
<p>sadf sdajkf hksadjfh s</p>
<p>Symbols:</p>
<p class="myChars">¢€£¥©®™‰µ·•…′″§¶ß‹›«»‘’“”&lt;&gt;≤≥–—¯‾¤¦¨¡¿ˆ˜°−±÷⁄×¹²³¼½¾ƒ∫∑∞√∼≅≈≠≡∈∉∋∏∧∨¬∩∪∂∀∃∅∇∗∝∠´¸ªº†‡ÀÁÂÃÅÆÇÈÉÊËĒÌÍÎÏĪÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØŒŠÙÚÛÜŪÝŸȲÞàáâãäåāæçèéêëēìíïīðñòóôõöøōœšùúûüýþÿȳΑΒΓΔΕΖΘΛΞΟΠΡΣΦΨΩαβγδεζηθικλμνξοπρςστυφψωℵϖℜϒ℘ℑ←↑→↓↔↵⇐⇒⇓⇔∴⊂⊃⊄⊆⊇⊕⊗⊥⋅⌈⌉⌊⌋⟨⟩◊♠♣♥♦</p>
```

Then your function:

```
var str = $('.myChars').text(),
letters = '';
for (var i = 0, len = str.length; i < len; i++) {
      if (str[i].match(/[¢€£¥©®™‰µ·•…′″§¶ß‹›«»‘’“”<>≤≥–—¯‾¤¦¨¡¿ˆ˜°−±÷⁄×¹²³¼½¾ƒ∫∑∞√∼≅≈≠≡∈∉∋∏∧∨¬∩∪∂∀∃∅∇∗∝∠´¸ªº†‡ÀÁÂÃÅÆÇÈÉÊËĒÌÍÎÏĪÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØŒŠÙÚÛÜŪÝŸȲÞàáâãäåāæçèéêëēìíïīðñòóôõöøōœšùúûüýþÿȳΑΒΓΔΕΖΘΛΞΟΠΡΣΦΨΩαβγδεζηθικλμνξοπρςστυφψωℵϖℜϒ℘ℑ←↑→↓↔↵⇐⇒⇓⇔∴⊂⊃⊄⊆⊇⊕⊗⊥⋅⌈⌉⌊⌋〈〉◊♠♣♥♦]/i)) {
           letters += '<span style="font:20px Arial;">' + str[i] + '</span>';
      }else {
          letters +=str[i];
      }
}
$('.myChars').html(letters);
```

Hope this Helps. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the solution! The problem though is that the HTML isn't generated directed by me but rather by TinyMCE making it a tad bit more difficult for me. Also, I should have mentioned this in my original question, sorry!

Comment: Actually, I got it fixed lol realized all I needed to do was .html() instead of .text() and make sure that that the symbols I'm matching with and surrounding with <span> tags aren't important to HTML syntax. I'll add that as the answer